# Silverlight adding object to collection before fully initialized?

Tags: c#, silverlight, xaml, datagrid

[image: screenshot]

What would cause the behavior exhibited in the third column?

The data displayed is the randomly created fields of an object stored in a collection. The collection is bound in the Main Page constructor after the collection is filled. I have stepped through the app a number of times in debug and the data is being regenerated for each row/object. But if I simply run without debugging, I get this behavior. The third property/column from the second item on repeats itself.

Relevant XAML:

```
<sdk:DataGrid AutoGenerateColumns="False" Grid.Column="1" Grid.Row="1" Height="400" HorizontalAlignment="Left" Margin="0,26,0,0" Name="dgList" VerticalAlignment="Top">
    <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Location}" CanUserResize="True" Width="Auto" x:Name="objLocation" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding Name}"  CanUserResize="True" Width="Auto" x:Name="objName" />
        <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding UPC}" CanUserResize="True" Width="Auto" x:Name="objUPC" />
    </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
</sdk:DataGrid>
```

Main_Page code behind:

```
    public Collection<MyClass> myList;

    public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        myList = new Collection<MyClass>();
        CreateHexGrid(8, 10, 30);
        dgList.ItemsSource = myList;
   }
```

...

```
    private void AddObjects(Point[, ,] HexPoint, int columns, int rows, double length)
    {
                    ....
                    string loc = col.ToString() + row.ToString();
                    myList.Add(new MyClass(loc));
    }
```

Behavior is consistent across browsers.

ADDED INFO ---

When I step through this using debug, I don't get this behavior. The third column generates an as-expected unique string of chars.

So, my question is ...  how is my MainPage adding the MyClass object into MyList before it finishes initializing?

Comment: can you the code as xaml and the code behind?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A late night debugging session with a friend reveals that my code is not too slow. He keyed onto the fact that the third column does eventually generate a new code, but not every time.

Short answer, a private Random class-level object was not ticking over. By making the Random object static, the class began to behave as expected.